# Laravel Route Model Binding return id null on product deletion

Tags: laravel

I'm using laravel 5.1.28. Here I'm just trying to create a **simple** application that can add, delete, and edit products but I noticed that when using the binding model, the $product instance just return null. I'm going to explain next, but first here are the full codes (without blade):

**In my route.php I have the following route for product:**

```
Route::model('products', 'App\Product'); 

Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'SentinelAdmin'), function ()
{

# Product Management admin backend
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'products'), function () {
    Route::get('/', array('as' => 'products', 'uses' => 'ProductController@index'));
    Route::get('create', 'ProductController@create');
    Route::post('create', 'ProductController@store');
    Route::get('{productId}/delete', array('as' => 'delete/product', 'uses' => 'ProductController@destroy'));
    Route::get('{productId}/confirm-delete', array('as' => 'confirm-delete/product', 'uses' => 'ProductController@getModalDelete'));
    Route::get('{productId}/restore', array('as' => 'restore/product', 'uses' => 'ProductController@getRestore'));
    Route::get('{productId}', array('as' => 'products.show', 'uses' => 'ProductController@show'));
});

    Route::resource('products', 'ProductController');

});
```

**So, this is my simple database migration:**

```
class CreateProductsTable extends Migration
{

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('user_id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('description')->nullable();
        $table->string('category')->nullable();
        $table->decimal('price')->nullable(); 
        $table->integer('quantity')->nullable(); 
        $table->tinyInteger('in_stock')->nullable(); //0 - no, 1 - yes
        $table->string('photos')->default('default_product_photo.jpg')->nullable(); //add one first
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('products', function (Blueprint $table) {

    });
}
}
```

In my Product.php model, I have this:

```
**class Product extends Model
 {
   protected $table = 'products';
   protected $guarded = ['id'];
   protected $fillable = [
    'user_id',
    'name',
    'description',
    'category',
    'price',
    'quantity',
    'in_stock',
    'photos',
];
}**
```

**This are the 2 functions that I have in the ProductController.php**

For the 1st FUNCTION getModalDelete below, it will find the product id, and display a confirmation box to delete the product. If confirmed button is clicked, the route delete/product/{id} will be called and the destroy method is then called the (2nd function). The 2nd function is matter:

```
class ProductController extends Controller
{
  //1st FUNCTION
  public function getModalDelete(Request $request, $id) 
  {
    $product_id = Product::where('id', '=', $id)->firstOrFail();
    $model = 'products'; ////testing s
    $confirm_route = $error = null;
    try {
        $confirm_route = route('delete/product', ['id' => $product_id]);
        return View('admin/layouts/modal_confirmation', compact('error', 'model', 'confirm_route'));
    } catch (ProductNotFoundException $e) {

        $error = trans('product/message.error.delete', compact('id'));
        return View('admin/layouts/modal_confirmation', compact('error', 'model', 'confirm_route'));
    }
  }

  //2nd FUNCTION
  public function destroy(Product $product)
  {
    Product::destroy($product);
   // $product->forceDelete(); //doesn't work either

    //dd($product); //Weird that it returns null.

    //$success = Lang::get('products/message.success.delete');

    //return Redirect::route('admin.products.index')->with('success', $success);

  }
}
```

But if I changed the parameter of  the function from

```
public function destroy(Product $product)
{
}
```

to

```
public function destroy($id)
{
}
```

it works. But I just don't know why the parameter (Product $product) doesn't work here using route model binding. The $product just return null. but the $id returns a value.

Comment: I think this is the same issue I had the other day with route model binding change in your route `{productId}` to `{product}` it should work :)

Comment: Actually just realised the above won't work as your using 5.1 does in 5.2 check out the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#route-model-binding you need to bind the model to the router.

Comment: Yeah it doesn't work. I want to try this on 5.2 but I have few packages that doesn't support 5.2 though .. :(

Comment: Ah sucks but yeah `Route::model('product', 'Product');` should get it working for you in theory. With the change mentioned above of changing the parameter name.

Comment: I have tried pulling the s out but doesn't work either. Just now, I registered the route by following the documentation, running composer dump-autoload. still doesn't work. the product just returns a null value.

Comment: I have a question here, what is the different between Route::model('product', 'Product'); with the 's' in Route::model('products', 'Product'); I thought that the 's' is following my table name. Still changing this doesn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100997/discussion-between-maxi32-and-mark-davidson).

Comment: I don't suspect this will cause the issue experienced, but you should use either `guarded` or `fillable`, but **not** both. Since you have less `guarded`, I'd just remove the `fillable` array. See [mass assignments](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#mass-assignment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out it was the issue on front end template:

Actually I tried changing from

```
Route::model('products', 'App\Product');
```

to

```
Route::model('product', 'App\Product');
```

before attempted to post this question and it did not work due to the issue of the frontend template that I'm using. So, the answers from @Mark Davidson changing the

```
Route::model('products', 'Product');
```

to

```
Route::model('product', 'Product');
```

and changing the parameter of

```
{productId}
```

to

```
{product}
```

works perfectly.

The route of deleting the product in the front end has some issue. I can delete the product using the URL browser but clicking on the delete button doesn't popup and I was unable to debug the value. Somehow, the button popup appear if I change the

```
Route::model('product', 'App\Product');
```

to

```
Route::model('products', 'App\Product');
```

but it returns the $product instance to null. Problem solved.